# Definition of semisimple modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

M is a semisimple module iff every submodule of M is a direct summand ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_module) is the definition of semisimple modules, and this is the property 3), but this property can be replaced with "every submodule of M is $\textit{isomorphic}$ to a direct summand of M"?

Comment: Of course not. For example, every submodule of $\Bbb{Z}$ is isomorphic either to $\Bbb{Z}$ or $0$, which are direct summands of $\Bbb{Z}$; however $\Bbb{Z}$ is not a semisimple $\Bbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: Thank you, that is a nice example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course not. For example, every submodule of $\Bbb{Z}$ is isomorphic either to $\Bbb{Z}$ or $0$, which are direct summands of $\Bbb{Z}$, however $\Bbb{Z}$ is not a semisimple $\Bbb{Z}$-module.